# pf NAT to specified destinations only

Tags: macos, networking, routes, ip, nat

In order to share a VPN connection, which is configured for specified websites only (while the other traffic goes as is), I created the following pf rule:

```
nat pass on vtap0 from bridge1:network to any -> (vtap0)
```

It works, but naturally *all* traffic now goes through VPN. I modified the rule to:

```
nat pass on vtap0 from bridge1:network to [allowed website IP XX.XX.XX.XX] -> (vtap0)
```

but no change - all traffic still seems to go through VPN. Here I stuck. So, how to create a NAT rule that is applicable to specified destination IPs only?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct rules are:

```
nat on vtap0 from bridge1:network to XX.XX.XX.XX -> (vtap0)
nat on en0 from bridge1:network to any -> (en0)
```